# How to upload images to website gallery through site not dreamweaver?

Tags: javascript, php, database, image, upload

I have built a very simple website and I have started to struggle with keeping a gallery up to date let alone the rest of the site.

With each new photographs I have the task of resizing, compressing, creating thumbs and then manually adding each piece of the puzzle to the website via my text editor which, if there are 50 - 75 photographs can take me a very long time.

I would absolutely love to be able to either write or use a plugin that will allow upload of images via an automatic/multi uploader, whether I put it into a private "Admin" page or something.

I just know that there must be a quicker way of doing this. At the moment I am using Lightbox as the gallery but will of course change this plugin if I need to.

How could I achieve such plugin so that images can be added to the existing gallery

Comment: Are you using a database to store some data?

Comment: might google "popular image upload plugins" with a bit more success :)

Comment: @Eranda As it stands I am just using a host and domain from 1and1 but I do believe I can create a database with my package

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Its not the design of the upload that im after its the process of uploading for it to go automatically in to the existing gallery

Comment: you can use the php GD library in php, submit using html and resize using php. But i see a answer using wordpress, it would be easy enough for your cousin to learn himself!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like Picasa might work for your needs - http://picasa.google.co.uk/

They say you can embed their galleries by copying-and-pasting a script into your page.

You won't get as much freedom in the design as hosting your own CMS, but it has the benefit that you don't have to worry about keeping it patched.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given any thought on using Wordpress or Joomla, they're excellent on managing content. They're fairly easy to implement and learn. The customition depends on the css, js and html skills. I'll go for one of these if your app is not performance critical...Hope it helps

Comment: I have thought about it but again I really don't have much time to rebuild the site for wordpress. Here is the current site as it stands, I know it wouldnt take long but I would struggle. http://www.stevehillcarpentry.co.uk

Answer (score -1):

Here are some plugins to resize/crop pictures [TimThumb](https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/), [PHPThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks I am sure they will come in handy